# How can I edit a .class in rt.jar to support arbitrary Elliptic Curves

Tags: java, netbeans, elliptic-curve, .class-file, rt.jar

I am trying to change the `ECParameters` class in `sun.security.ec`. I need to do this in order to get arbitrary curves working, and I already downloaded the OpenJDK source, edited the code and compiled it again.

I unpacked my current `rt.jar` and replaced all the files in `sun.security.ec` with my own compiled files. Everything looks right, but when I compile it again and try to start netbeans nothing happens..

Does anyone know what I did wrong, and how I should do it properly?

Edit: I have read that it is not recommended to edit these classes, but this particular class even has a piece of code that is commented out.

```
// The code below is incomplete.
//It is left as a starting point for a complete parsing implementation.
```

Comment: Why not package your implementation as a patch and submit it to the OpenJDK project? See http://openjdk.java.net/contribute/ for details.

Comment: *but when I compile it again and try to start netbeans nothing happens..* — You mean: Netbeans does not start? Or your program does not run?

Comment: I'm not that good of a java programmer yet I feel.. I'm actually a bit surprised that nobody did it already, since Elliptic Curve Cryptography is on the rise.

Comment: My netbeans won't even start, i'm running this on ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Perhaps there is no corresponding bug. The first step to get this implemented in the JDK, is to file a bug report at http://bugreport.java.com Without a bug report, nothing will happen. Potentially ever.

Comment: I'd try to make sure that Netbeans uses an unpatched JDK...

Comment: Thanks! i'll file a bug report and hope they will do something with it. Since the same code is commented in java 6,7 and 8. 
Still I wonder if its possible to modify the rt.jar? I've tried adding my own .class file to it and it just made a different directory inside the jar, so it didn't change anything. But it IS possible to modify rt.jar somehow? But not I can't delete that particular directory anymore.. I'm a bit lost to speak the truth...

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to *change* compiled JDK classes. Why you don't use "normal" ways to implement your case? As you already mentioned that it isn't a good way you could use the commented code you've found e.g. to implement an util class.

Comment: I might try this as well, but I'm not sure how to make this work.. Since it appears to be quite hard to override classes from rt.jar . Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/a/30422178/5061639 might help me with trying this.

Comment: Well, overriding ECParameters will not work since the class is final.

Comment: I also forgot to mention that for example when using Keytool, it also uses that particular class. So it can not handle arbitrary curves, that's one of the reasons why I am opting to edit the class itself.